# MySQL Stored Procedure returns null

Tags: mysql, procedure

I did go through the similar questions and their answers of SO but it didn't help.
Here is my procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test//
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN 
DECLARE intime TIME;
SET intime:=(SELECT intime FROM new_attendance  WHERE empid='xxx' AND DATE(dt)='2013-08-02');
SELECT intime;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

When I execute this line of code it works and returns proper value:

```
SELECT empid FROM new_attendance  WHERE empid='xxx' AND DATE(dt)='2013-08-02'
```

but it's not working inside procedure. i appreciate your help. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: erm, is `empid` of type `TIME`?

Comment: @hjpotter92 sry... it's **intime**, edited in question, tks for pointing out.

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos it is **intime**, please sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, variable assignment in MySQL takes a `=` syntax, not a `:=` one.

**EDIT**: Strike the above, it seems that both syntaxes are supported after all...

Second, wouldn't be simpler to eliminate the `intime` variable altogether and just do

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test//
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN 
SELECT intime FROM new_attendance  WHERE empid='xxx' AND DATE(dt)='2013-08-02';
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: @Sunny Also, if `empid` is `INT` or its derivative, you don't need to enclose it in quotes. At ALL.

Comment: @Sunny You're welcome. If my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it as the correct one.

Comment: @geomagas Yes, we can use "=" and ":=" both for assignment but only while used with SET, otherwise '=" checks for equality 
- MySQL Documentation says :)

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention.